# Nighwatch find multiple elements with unique css selectors

Tags: css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I'm writing some e2e testing with Nightwatch, but I have some problems with css selectors. I need to click the last element of a user menu. The menu is framework generated, so I can't really assign an `id` to the last element, so I decided to proceed with the following code:

```
browser.waitForElmentVisibleAndClick = function(element) {
  this.waitForElementVisible(element, DEFAULT_WAITING_TIME);
  this.click(element);

  return this;
};

.waitForElmentVisibleAndClick('.user-menu-items:last-child')
```

The problem is that the element is not clicked. In the test warning I see the following:

> Warn: WaitForElement found 2 elements for selector
>   ".user-menu-items:last-child". Only the first one will be checked.

How it can find two elements with the selector :last-child? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sound like there are multiple `.user-menu-items` on the page.
If that's true, you can be more specific by including it's parent.

`.waitForElmentVisibleAndClick('.parent .user-menu-items:last-child')`